# Python using sort with function gives TypeError: date_compare() missing 1 required positional argument: error

Tags: python, sorting, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I am completely new to Python so please excuse my lack of knowledge.  I am writing a script to create AWS EC2 snapshots and then delete any older snapshots specified in the script.  I took some code from other scripts which appear to have been written in an older Python version (I am using 3.3.2).

```
#Built with Python 3.3.2
import boto.ec2
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
from boto.ec2.regioninfo import RegionInfo
from boto.ec2.snapshot import Snapshot
from datetime import datetime
import sys

aws_access_key = str(input("AWS Access Key: "))
aws_secret_key = str(input("AWS Secret Key: "))
regionname = str(input("AWS Region Name: "))
regionendpoint = str(input("AWS Region Endpoint: "))
region = RegionInfo(name=regionname, endpoint=regionendpoint)
conn = EC2Connection(aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_key, region = region)
print (conn)

volumes = conn.get_all_volumes()
print ("%s" % repr(volumes))

vol_id = str(input("Enter Volume ID to snapshot: "))
keep = int(input("Enter number of snapshots to keep:  "))
volume = volumes[0]
description = str(input("Enter volume snapshot description: "))


if volume.create_snapshot(description):
    print ('Snapshot created with description: %s' % description)

snapshots = volume.snapshots()
print (snapshots)

def date_compare(snap1, snap2):
    if snap1.start_time < snap2.start_time:
        return -1
    elif snap1.start_time == snap2.start_time:
        return 0
    return 1

snapshots.sort(key=date_compare)
delta = len(snapshots) - keep
for i in range(delta):
    print ('Deleting snapshot ') + snapshots[i].description
    snapshots[i].delete()
```

When using sort to order the snapshots I am calling a function to compare dates to work out which is the newest and oldest snapshots.  When snapshots.sort(key=date_compare) runs I get the following error:

```
    snapshots.sort(key=date_compare)
TypeError: date_compare() missing 1 required positional argument: 'snap2'
```

Pretty sure I am doing something very basic wrong but would really appreciate some help to get this working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your function `date_compare` takes two arguments, `def date_compare(snap1, snap2)` -- but the sort function will only ever pass one arg to the function provided to `key` -- not two items.  The `key` keyword is used to tell sort on which field to compare within a object; it's not used to actually compare two different objects.  You want to use the `cmp` keyword to pass a custom compare function.  Pretty sure you just mean to use the `cmp` keyword instead of `key`.

See this for more:

- python2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted
- python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

To understand the how `key` function should work, let's take a simpler example to see how this works.  Let's say I have a list of tuples:

```
>>> my_data = [(0, 'Z',), (1, 'Y',), (2, 'W')]
```

If I just sort this data I get:

```
>>> sorted(my_data)
[(0, 'Z'), (1, 'Y'), (2, 'W')]
```

However, if I want to sort on the second item of the tuple, I can write a simple function like this:

```
>>> def get_second(item):
...    return item[1]
>>>
>>> sorted(my_data, key=get_second)
[(2, 'W'), (1, 'Y'), (0, 'Z')]
```

So now it's sorting on the second item.  Note, often a simple lambda function is used to accomplish things like this:

```
>>> sorted(my_data, key=lambda item: item[1])
[(2, 'W'), (1, 'Y'), (0, 'Z')]
```

which saves you having to define a simple function like this before hand.

To use the `cmp` keyword to accomplish the same sorting it works like this:

```
>>> def compare(left, right):
...     if left[1] < right[1]:
...         return -1
...     elif left[1] == right[1]:
...         return 0
...     else:
...         return 1
>>> sorted(my_data, cmp=compare) 
[(2, 'W'), (1, 'Y'), (0, 'Z')]
```

Last, just note, `sorted(seq)` is the same as `seq.sort()` -- takes the same args, kwargs, etc.  Just `sorted` is a copy whereas `seq.sort()` is an in-place, destructive operation.

Comment: Thanks I actually worked around this using a function to convert cmp to key by doing this:    from functools import cmp_to_key                                   snapshots.sort(key=cmp_to_key(date_compare))                                         this worked but based on what you mentioned above I could just replace key= with cmp= and that would achieve the same result??

Comment: I think just changing `key` to `cmp` is more standard, straight forward.  Can you upvote and accept my answer?

Comment: no problems, answer accepted, only just created my account so my rep doesnt allow me to vote yet.  Thanks!!